# how can I exctract attribute value using JAVA regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have such string:

```
<a href="https://host-test.com/create?userName=test3&amp;user-mail=myemail@gmail.com&amp;id=14b72820-3855-4f2b-9a39-543ced6784a0&amp;downloadurl=https://host-test.com:443/123/rest/tmp-z7vvymo3wmfzke/vfs/v2/downloadzip/&amp;projectid=d29ya3NwYWNleXFpYXlwZjgwb2sxNDA2MjovY3JlYXRlQWNj:createAcc;" style="font-family:Myriad Pro,arial,tahoma,serif;color:#fff;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold" title="Confirm tenant creation" target="_blank">
                            <div style="font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;border-radius:5px;width:120px;min-height:40px;line-height:40px;border:1px solid #577e15;color:#fff;text-align:center;background:#e77431;margin:15px 0 15px">
                                Confirm
                            </div>
                        </a>
```

and I need extract using regexp only href value:

```
https://host-test.com/create?userName=test3&amp;user-mail=myemail@gmail.com&amp;id=14b72820-3855-4f2b-9a39-543ced6784a0&amp;downloadurl=https://host-test.com:443/123/rest/tmp-z7vvymo3wmfzke/vfs/v2/downloadzip/&amp;projectid=d29ya3NwYWNleXFpYXlwZjgwb2sxNDA2MjovY3JlYXRlQWNj:createAcc;
```

also href value each time can be different shorter or longer

Comment: `I need extract using regexp only` just to make sure, you cant use any parsers?

Comment: I think I [read somewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) that you can't parse HTML with RegEx or you'd unleash hell on earth or something.

Comment: no, I know how to do this with parsers..

Comment: @MikeChristensen I prefer [the less subjective article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myString.replaceFirst(myString, "^<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+)\".*", , "$1");
```

assuming myString contains your string with the `a` element.

As the href attributes cannot be nested, this should be fine and no full HTML parser is needed. A restriction is that it will only find href attributes in double quotes.

Comment: You can just use a regex and capture that pattern. `<a[^>]*\shref=['"](.*)["']`

Comment: Your regex would give a wrong result for e. g. `<a href="a" id="y"/>`. Then it would capture `a" id="y`.

Comment: Aww your right sorry I missed where it had additional tags in the string, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular string you can try something like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a\\shref=\"([^\"]+)");
//or if you cant use group numbers use look-behind mechanism like
//Pattern.compile("(?<=<a\\shref=\")[^\"]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

but if your string can change (like href atrubute can have other atributes before it) it can not work as expected. That is one of the reasons to use parsers rather then regex.